# SQL Join - list the number of each type of event that each person has worked

Tags: mysql

All, Something is just not working. I am trying to list the number of each type of event that each person has worked.

Out put should include the last name, first name, event_type and the number of events.

Below is mysql query I wrote,

```
select staff.lname, staff.fname, event.event_type, count(event_staff.event_id) 
from `event_staff` 
JOIN event 
ON event.event_id = event_staff.event_id 
JOIN staff 
ON staff.ssn = event_staff.ssn 
group by event_staff.ssn
```

Result of the above Query:

[image: Result of the above query]

Below are the tables:

[image: Staff Table]
[image: Event Table]
[image: event_Staff table]

Clearly, the result of my query is not producing the correct result.I would appreciate any help..Thanks.

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: The expected out put is for each staff member, I should list the number of each type of event that he or she has worked.
-- The output should include the last name, first name, event_type and the number of events.

Please let me know if my answer is not clear..

Comment: You should group by the event type also. As a rule it is better to always group by the selected fields which you are not aggregating. But `group by staff.ssn, event.event_type` should do the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should group by the event type also. As a rule it is better to always group by the selected fields which you are not aggregating. But:

```
group by staff.ssn, event.event_type
```

...should do the trick as `staff.lname`, `staff.fname` are functionally dependent on the `ssn`.

Comment: NB: you seem to try to accept multiple answers. You can only accept one. On the other hand you can vote for multiple answers.

Answer (score 1):

With your query, you'll get count of total events (all the types) a person worked for. In order to get count for each type of event, add `event_type` in `group by` clauese and it'll work as expected:

```
select staff.lname, staff.fname, event.event_type, count(event_staff.event_id) 
from `event_staff` 
JOIN event 
ON event.event_id = event_staff.event_id 
JOIN staff 
ON staff.ssn = event_staff.ssn 
group by event_staff.ssn,event.event_type;
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks @Harshil Doshi, your answer is very helpful!!

Answer (score 1):

The `GROUP BY` should have all the unaggregated columns in the `SELECT`.  I would also recommend table aliases:

```
select s.lname, s.fname, e.event_type, count(es.event_id) 
from event_staff es JOIN
     event e
     ON e.event_id = es.event_id JOIN
     staff s
     ON s.ssn = es.ssn 
group by s.lname, s.fname, e.event_type;
```

What is really important from your perspective is including the `event_type` in the `GROUP BY`.

Note:  You can still aggregate by `ssn` -- this is important if two different staff members might have the same name.